# c# - Powerpoint -addIn- ribbon is not visible

Tags: c#, .net, add-in, powerpoint, ribbon

I am new to C# and .Net. I am currently creating a PPT addIn. Initially i have added a ribbon and some buttons to it, but finally i had to delete it and add a new ribbon. but this new ribbon does not showup in the PPT. PPT loads without the new tab (and buttons). Am i missing any settings (like setting a ribbon as the default one to the PPT etc). Please somebody help me here.

Thanks,
Sri.

Comment: Is the ribbon's type set to `Microsoft.PowerPoint.Presentation`?

Comment: I am using an XML ribbon. Just now I ran it in Release mode and everything seems to be fine. The ribbon and the buttons show up in Release mode, but not in Debug mode. Is this how it supposed to work?